# In Youtrack we would like to enable Time Tracking only to assignee of the issue

Tags: youtrack

We would like to update workflow, where Time Tracking module should only be visible to Assignee of the Issue.

We've tried assert, required but that only allows restriction on main field but Time tracking entries still gets generated.

Comment: Take a look at the comments here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-40413#tab=Comments there are questions for you

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't do that via workflow, because you can't limit visibility of anything from workflows.

FYI: there is a permission 'Update Work Item' which allows users to add work items. If a user doesn't have this permission, he can't add work items in the Time Tracking tab. There is a permission 'Read Work Item' which allows to view work items. In some cases you can configure your permissions so that only some users can view/edit work items.